# How to select elements using CSS selector who's attribute can have multiple values

Tags: css, web, css-selectors

sample condition is

**(type=text || type=password || type=search || type = tel) && readonly!=true && disabled!=true && focused**

for example,

```
1.<input type="text"></input>
2.<input type="password"></input>
3.<input type="search"></input>
4.<input type="text" readonly></input>
5.<input type="password" disabled></input>
```

only **1,2,3 should selected**, **4 & 5 shouldn't be selected**. I already googled, but no use. can anybody help me?

**(without using any js libs like jquery)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is a combination of using the attribute selector and the `not` selector and the `:focus` selector.

Here's a JsFiddle and the CSS below: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/bdb63/

```
input[type="text"]:not([readonly]):not([disabled]):focus,
input[type="password"]:not([readonly]):not([disabled]):focus,
input[type="search"]:not([readonly]):not([disabled]):focus,
input[type="tel"]:not([readonly]):not([disabled]):focus { /* ... */ }
```

Though, depending on your form, you may find it easier to style all inputs *not* a certain type in a single rule. Something like:

```
input:not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]):not([readonly]):not([disabled]):focus { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Excellent :) This is what I exactly needed. +1000 for you :)

Comment: That is some hardcore CSSing just there. Great job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  some css...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. I need to match multiple logical **||** and **&&** conditions. Is it possible?                                               (type=text || type=password || type=search || type = tel) && readonly!=true && disabled!=true && focused

Answer (score 0):

You can check for attribute presence rather than value, then use the cascade to handle the exception.

```
input[type] {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

input[readonly] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Example running on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EU9g/).

**Update for comment**: this should do exactly what you are asking for.

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=search], input[type=tel] {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

input[readonly], input[disabled] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Using the cascade to deal with the exceptions makes your selectors much less verbose.

Comment: i don't want to select if it type=="date", my condition is "(type=text || type=password || type=search || type = tel) && readonly!=true && disabled!=true"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `type`-selector without any assigned type:

```
input[type] {
    background: red;
}
```

Works even with `querySelector/All`

```
document.querySelector('input[type]').className = 'foo';
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/59kk3/

Answer (score 0):

For your exact conditional of `(type=text || type=password || type=search || type = tel) && readonly!=true && disabled!=true`:

```
input[type="text"]:enabled:read-write,
input[type="password"]:enabled:read-write,
input[type="search"]:enabled:read-write,
input[type="tel"]:enabled:read-write {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Note that the `:read-write` pseudo-element isn't supported by Internet Explorer yet, so you can also do this:

```
input[type="text"]:not([readonly]):enabled,
input[type="password"]:not([readonly]):enabled,
input[type="search"]:not([readonly]):enabled,
input[type="tel"]:not([readonly]):enabled {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Theoretically this should work in all modern browsers and IE 9+.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can helps you:

```
input:enabled:not([readonly]):focus { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: can you please expand your answer? _Why_ do you think that this might be the solution?

Answer (score -2):

Using only vanilla JS, you would have to get all input elements and then traverse the array to get select the items you need. Something like this:

```
    var result;
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
       var readonly = elements[i].hasOwnProperty("readonly");
       var disabled = elements[i].hasOwnProperty("disabled");
       if ((elements[i].type == "text"  || elements[i].type == "password") && !readonly && !disabled){
      result.push(elements[i];
   }
```

This is untested code but it should work.

Comment: Of course, you should add your conditions to the if, I only tested for type being text or password.